# Can we conclude that $f : (X,d) \longrightarrow (Y, \tau)$ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $(Y,\tau)$ be a topological space and $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a bijective continuous map. Suppose that there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that for all $M \gt 0$ the restriction $f\rvert_{\overline {B_d(x_0,M)}} : \overline {B_d(x_0,M)} \longrightarrow f \left (\overline {B_d(x_0,M)} \right )$ is a homeomorphism. Can we conclude that $f$ itself is a homeomorphism?

**My Attempt** $:$ I guess that $f$ can be shown to be open and hence $f$ is a homeomorphism. Let $U \subseteq X$ be open and $x \in U.$ Choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and $M \gt 0$ such that $B_d (x, \varepsilon) \subseteq U \cap B_d (x_0, M).$ Since $f \rvert_{\overline {B_d(x_0,M)}}$ is a homeomorphism it follows that $f \left (B_d (x, \varepsilon) \right )$ is open in $f \left (\overline {B_d(x_0,M)} \right ).$ Since $f \left (B_d (x, \varepsilon) \right ) \subseteq f(U)$ and $x \in U$ were arbitrarily taken  so if we can somehow show that $f(x)$ is an interior point of $f \left (B_d(x, \varepsilon) \right )$ then we are done with proof. This is where I am getting stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. Consider the ray $X = [0, \infty)$ with its standard metric; then there is a continuous bijection $f: X \to S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) = 1/(x + 1) \bmod \mathbb{Z}$. Informally, this wraps $X$ around the circle, with $0$ being sent to some point and $f(x)$ getting asymptotically close to this point from the other side as $x \to \infty$. The image of any closed interval (of finite length) maps homeomorphically onto its image, but $X$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$.

By the way, this is a pretty common counterexample that comes up in differential topology, and it shows why one must be careful when trying to think about embeddings.

Comment: Can we someway modify the statement so that $f$ becomes a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Anacardium If you instead require that a neighborhood of each point $x$ maps homeomorphically onto a neighborhood of $f(x)$, then it is a homeomorphism, since the (set-theoretic) inverse map is clearly continuous, since continuity can be checked locally. But this seems too obvious, and I'm not sure if there is a good modification that is "local on the source" in the way that the original problem is stated.

Comment: $:$ Please have a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Cuk.png  My question is motivated from Theorem $A$ and in fact I don't understand how $\widehat {\sigma}$ is open. The exact same technique is used here.

Comment: I think there's a subtle error in this proof: it seems to assume that because the restriction to $\overline{B(0, M)}$ is a homeomorphism onto its (closed) image, the image of $B(0, M)$ is open *in the codomain*. This is confusing because it *is* true that $\hat{\sigma}(B(0, M))$ is open in the subspace topology of $\hat{\sigma}(\overline{B(0, M)})$, but the property of being open depends on the ambient space. So, the text is flawed.

Comment: $:$ I have modified this proof just now. I showed that $\sigma$ is a perfect map and hence closed. Since $\sigma = \widehat {\sigma} \circ \pi$ it follows then that $\widehat {\sigma}$ is closed and hence a homeomorphism as $\widehat {\sigma}$ is already shown to be a bijective continuous map. But I wonder how such flawed proof is accepted in the prestigious journal like *Proceedings of American Mathematical Society* and granted by reputed organization like *NASA.*